# Shell/Perl script to find and print string and some

Tags: perl, shell, awk, grep

I'm currently trying to write a simple shell script that will read in a file, look for a certain string and then print that string and a few characters after. The context of this request is that I have a set of data files which I'd like to run through. The files contain a bunch of elemental ionization values. I'm trying to find the element and the print out its ionization values.

An issue here is that the data file also contains elemental temperatures at certain ionizations, so there are at least two different instances in which the element will appear in the file. Each data file is pretty standard so I could go about this by counting which element occurrence I desire and print only that one, but I was wondering if there were a better way to do this. Say first find the location of the section header "ionization values" and then print the first said element values that occur.

Does this make sense? If not, don't hesitate to ask for clarification!

Here's a sample of what the input can look like:

```
Log10  Mean Ionisation (over radius)
Hydrogen   -1.881 -0.006-10.514 (H2)
Helium     -1.433 -0.034 -1.410
Lithium    -3.769 -0.001 -2.531 -4.765
Beryllium  -1.896 -0.704 -0.107 -2.060 -5.793
Boron      -3.592 -0.118 -0.677 -1.570 -4.884
Carbon     -3.082 -0.350 -0.259 -2.707 -3.577 -8.864

Log10 Mean Temperature (over radius)
Hydrogen    4.068  4.068  4.068 (H2)
Helium      4.068  4.068  4.068
Lithium     4.068  4.068  4.068  4.068
Beryllium   4.068  4.068  4.068  4.068  4.068
Boron       4.068  4.068  4.068  4.068  4.068
Carbon      4.068  4.068  4.068  4.068  4.068  4.068
```

As for an output, all I really need is just the values an elements. Print them to console is fine

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming what you are showing is a sample input file, show also your desired output given that input.

Comment: Two things: what should the output look like, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save this in a file and call it with 2 parameters, the first is the name of the element, the second is the name of the file to search.  The element name is case sensitive:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -n "
    /Log10  Mean Ionisation (over radius)/,/^[[:space:]]*$/ {
        /^${1:?}/ p
    }
" "${2:?}"
```

The `sed` command by default prints nothing (`-n`), then, for the lines between "Log10  Mean Ionisation (over radius)" and the next blank line, it will search for the pattern (element) given by the first script parameter, at the beginning of the line (`/^${1:?}`), and if found, prints the line (`p`).

The `${1:?}` and `${2:?}` notation to reference the positional parameters, causes the shell to print an error message and exit if either of the parameters are not set.

Comment: Thanks for this!!

I think I am going to use the grep command to find the line I wish to print then awk to print only a section of that line. Now figuring out how to find the first occurrence of the Element after a certain header. This I just used:

grep -A 5 'Log10  Mean Ionisation (over radius)' FILE | grep 'Carbon' | awk...

This may be improper to do, but it works!


Thanks for the help!!!